# MOXy does not import other schemas that it generates

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I follow the instruction [here](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Invoking_schemagen_programatically.html) in order to generate the XML Schema for my annotated classes. I am using MOXy for the underlying implementation of JAXB because I need its certain features like `@XmlPath` and how it handles the primitive types for `XmlAdapter`.

The code in the link above generates schema into two schema files, i.e. one contains the rules for simple and complex types and the other one contains only the schema for the enum types. Ideally, I want them to be in a single schema file but that is not the main issue for now.

When I use the Sun implementation of JAXB, it generates the schema and imports the other one. However, when I switch to use MOXy implementation, it does not import the other schema, see the example below:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns0="http://my/schema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://my/schema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- this bit is missing when MOXy is used -->
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
...
</xsd:schema>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is the bit of code I used:

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class, IdentifierType.class);
    SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
    context.generateSchema(sor);
```

`Person` is a standard POJO and `IdentifierType` is enum. They are both annotated with JAXB annotations, like `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlEnum`, etc. (I could provide more codes if needed)

Comment: At which point are you importing the XML schema?  If you are referring to generating classes from an XML schema then MOXy uses the XJC component from the reference implementation for this.

Comment: I am not generating the classes from schema. I am generating the schema from the classes. the import was present only when i used Sun implementation which is what i would like it to be.

Comment: What does your Java model look like?  Also which version of EclipseLink MOXy are you using?

Comment: I am using EclipseLink MOXy 2.4.0. I will add the code for the model in a minute.

Comment: I have added an answer with code.  Does it look like what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - ISSUE FIXED**

Thank you for entering the followng bug for this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/400366

This has now been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5.0 streams.  You can try out the fix using a nightly download starting February 12th, 2013 from think below:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

I have not been able to recreate the issue that you are seeing.  Below is what I have tried so far.

**SCENARIO #1 - `Person` and `IdentifierType` in Same Namespace**

If the POJO and the Enum are in the same namespace then only one XML schema will be generated.

**Person (POJO)**

```
package forum14778338;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    private IdentifierType identifierType;

    public IdentifierType getIdentifierType() {
        return identifierType;
    }

    public void setIdentifierType(IdentifierType identifierType) {
        this.identifierType = identifierType;
    }

}
```

**IdentifierType**

```
package forum14778338;

public enum IdentifierType {

    FOO,
    BAR

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum14778338;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName)
                    throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="person">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="identifierType" type="identifierType" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="person" type="person"/>
   <xsd:simpleType name="identifierType">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="FOO"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="BAR"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**SCENARIO #2 - `Person` and `IdentifierType` in Different Namespaces**

If the POJO and Enum are in different namespaces then two XML schemas should be generated.

**IdentifierType**

I have added the `@XmlType` annotation to the `IdentifierType` enum to put it in a different namespace.

```
package forum14778338;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlEnum
@XmlType(namespace="foo")
public enum IdentifierType {

    FOO,
    BAR

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns0="foo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:import schemaLocation="schema2.xsd" namespace="foo"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="person">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="identifierType" type="ns0:identifierType" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="person" type="person"/>
</xsd:schema>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns0="foo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="foo">
   <xsd:simpleType name="identifierType">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
         <xsd:enumeration value="FOO"/>
         <xsd:enumeration value="BAR"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am trying to reduce my code but I cannot recreate the issue when the code is very small. I appear that it happens in my project which contains many classes. Please allow me to try to recreate and pin point the problem in a smaller project and I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I have found the problem. The identifierType class is in a different package which contains no `package-info.java` file so JAXB generates two schema. Once I put `package-info.java` in all packages it only generate one schema. However, when it generate two schemas, MOXy doesn't import the other one, unlike Sun implementation.

Comment: Since I know how to make it generates a single, this question seems to be irrelevance anymore. However, it might be useful for others. Thank you so much for your very quick and helpful reply.

Comment: I have just seen that you have updated your answer. The problem appears to be the second scenario of your answer.

Comment: @gigadot - I'm still trying to capture the exact issue you are seeing.  Would you mind entering a bug for it?:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: @gigadot - Thank you for opening the bug.  A member of my team has taken a look at this and she thinks she has a fix.  We should be able to get a fix checked in on Monday.